# unoconv is too slow on my strong server

Tags: php

I have Ubuntu running on a VM with two virtual 2 Ghz CPUs and 4 gigabytes of RAM.

I run [`unoconv`](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv) from a PHP script to convert office files (`.doc`, `.ppt`, etc.) to PDF. The source files are not big (less than 1Mb). `unoconv` spends two seconds converting a source file. This is too long because I have hundreds of files to convert. Is this a normal amount of time for this process to take?

In addition of that, sometimes the server goes down after 2 or 3 days of tests. The administrator says it's because of 'unclosed' `unoconv` processes. How can I manage that from PHP? I think it's a server administration problem, not PHP problem. What can I do  to avoid this?

Comment: reading the doc/ppt files is already demanding lot of resources, creating a PDF file  is also heavy-resource operation. I don't hing you can speed it up. The best way is to make a seperate server with queue that converts files. 

For unclosed unoconv processes you can create a watchdog (some shell script that checks unoconv processes list and kills all very old one).

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not good in unix, so what should I do to run the process, get its id, wait it terminates conversion and kill it ?